# Calculating expected value of an unsigned random variable using CDF

Tags: probability-theory

following theorem is a very well-known theorem in probability theory:

> let $Y \geq 0$ and $\alpha > 0$ then
> $$\mathbb{E}[Y^{\alpha}] = \int_0^{\infty}\alpha Y^{\alpha-1}P(Y \geq y)dy = \mathbb{E}[Y^{\alpha}] = \int_0^{\infty}\alpha Y^{\alpha-1}P(Y > y)dy$$
> as an special case lettine $\alpha = 1$ yields the formula
> $$\mathbb{E}[Y] = \int_0^{\infty}P(Y > y)dy = \int_0^{\infty}(1-F_Y(y))dy$$

to prove this theorem I've argued as follows:

> for any fixed $\omega \in \Omega$:
> $$Y^{\alpha}(\omega) = \int_0^{Y(w)}\alpha y^{\alpha-1}dy =\int_0^{\infty}\alpha y^{\alpha-1}\chi_{[Y(\omega) > y]}dy$$
> integrating both sides w.r.t $\omega$ and using Fubini-Tonelli's theorem:
> $$\int_{\Omega}Y^{\alpha}dP = \int_{\Omega}[\int_0^{\infty}\alpha y^{\alpha-1}\chi_{[Y(\omega) > y]}dy]dP = \int_0^{\infty}\alpha y^{\alpha-1}dy \int_{\Omega}\chi_{[Y(\omega) > y]}dy]dP = \int_0^{\infty}\alpha y^{\alpha-1}P(Y > y)dy$$

I don't know how use previous theorem to prove the following result(I know how to prove it without the theorem).

> Let $X$ be a r.v valued in the nonnegative integers, then
> $$\mathbb{E}[X] = \Sigma_{n = 0}^{\infty}P(X > n)$$

Comment: $X$ taking non-negative integer values means that $\mathbb{P}(X>y)$ is constant for $y \in [n,n+1)$ whenever $n \in \mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$. By splitting the integral given by the formula up into these intervals, we get $$\mathbb{E}(X) = \int_0^\infty \mathbb{P}(X>y) \mathrm{d}y= \sum_{n\ge 0} \int_n^{n+1} \mathbb{P}(X>y)\mathrm{d}y= \sum_{n\ge0} \mathbb{P}(X>n).$$

Comment: Decompose your integral like $\int_0^{+\infty}=\sum_{n\in\mathbb N}\int_n^{n+1}$ and use that for $x\in(n,n+1)$, $X>x\iff X>n$ because $X$ is integer valued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the map $t\mapsto \mathbb P(X>t)$ is nonnegative, monotone convergence allows us to write
$$
\mathbb E[X] = \int_0^\infty \mathbb P(X>t)\ \mathsf dt = \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\mathbb P(X>t)\ \mathsf dt.
$$
If $\mathbb P(X\in\mathbb N\cup \{0\})=1$ then for $t\in(n,n+1)$ we have $\mathbb P(X>t)=\mathbb P(X>n)$. It follows that
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\mathbb P(X>t)\ \mathsf dt &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \int_n^{n+1}\mathbb P(X>n)\ \mathsf dt\\ &=  \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X>n)\int_n^{n+1}\ \mathsf dt\\ &= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \mathbb P(X>n).
\end{align}

Comment: got it, thanks.